# Photo list view like 'Google Photos'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, photos

I wonder if there is any control like `Photos application in android` in iOS.
Specifically  i need that `pinch gesture` to increase/decrease number of photos in list view(not pinch to zoom for single photo). Like currently single row showing 4 pics and I pinch list then list will have to show 3 photos then 2 and visa versa.

Comment: You can add the pinch gesture on your UICollectionView.

Comment: @Larme Photos app have specific animation while apply pinch gesture like they group photos months / week / days wise for appropriate size